# Process and eligibility for transit visa in Dubai

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dubai, emirates, flydubai

I am an Indian citizen and I have a Brussels - Dubai - Mumbai flight. This is the breakup of my journey:

- Brussels - Layover in Bucharest - Dubai [Blue Air and flydubai]
- Dubai - Bombay [Emirates, 9 hrs post previous flight]

My question is whether I am eligible for a transit visa, if so is it possible via flydubai? They do have provisions but on their website I can only see information for GCC nationals, which I am not.

Follow-up question, if I am not eligible for this visa, is there a standard UAE website I can visit to start the process or gather all the information?

Answer (score 1):

You are eligible for a transit visa but you need a confirmed and paid round trip booking to request a visa via FlyDubai https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/visas-and-passports/uae-visas  You can apply on https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/types-of-visa